# How to selectively convert elements of a list from string to integer

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have what might be a rudimentary question, but it has been causing me some difficulty and I thought someone might be able to help me out.

My issue is related to list comprehensions. I have data that looks like this and what I would like to do is convert columns 1,2,and 3 into integers.

```
['airport', '2007', '175702', '32788']
['airport', '2008', '173294', '31271']
['request', '2005', '646179', '81592']
['request', '2006', '677820', '86967']
['request', '2007', '697645', '92342']
['request', '2008', '795265', '125775']
['wandered', '2005', '83769', '32682']
['wandered', '2006', '87688', '34647']
['wandered', '2007', '108634', '40101']
['wandered', '2008', '171015', '64395']
```

I have tried code like the following:

```
test = [map(int,x) for x in raw_csv]
```

But when I run this and print the result I get an empty list. If someone knows how to do this I would really appreciate you showing me how. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is `raw_csv` a list? If so `for x in raw_csv` will iterate over the list of lists but access the individual elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your map syntax is a little off.

```
In [2]: stuff = [['airport', '2007', '175702', '32788'],
['airport', '2008', '173294', '31271'],
['request', '2005', '646179', '81592'],
['request', '2006', '677820', '86967'],
['request', '2007', '697645', '92342'],
['request', '2008', '795265', '125775'],
['wandered', '2005', '83769', '32682'],
['wandered', '2006', '87688', '34647'],
['wandered', '2007', '108634', '40101'],
['wandered', '2008', '171015', '64395'],]
In [4]: map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2]), int(x[3])], stuff)
Out[4]: 
[['airport', 2007, 175702, 32788],
 ['airport', 2008, 173294, 31271],
 ['request', 2005, 646179, 81592],
 ['request', 2006, 677820, 86967],
 ['request', 2007, 697645, 92342],
 ['request', 2008, 795265, 125775],
 ['wandered', 2005, 83769, 32682],
 ['wandered', 2006, 87688, 34647],
 ['wandered', 2007, 108634, 40101],
 ['wandered', 2008, 171015, 64395]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write a simple generator:

```
def safe_ints(sequence):
    for item in sequence
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except ValueError:
            yield item

test = [safe_ints(row) for row in rows]
```

EDIT: as OP wants, if conversion fails, item is returned as it was.

Or just simple function, that works on single token:

```
def try_int(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val
test = [map(try_int, row) for row in rows]
```

Comment: I think the simple function makes more sense here. The first version is basically just inlining that into `map`. (Also, if this is Python 2.x, you've changed his code from returning a list of lists to returning a list of iterators; if it's 3.x, it was already a list of iterators, but I suspect he didn't realize that and doesn't want it…)

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the first column is going to be non-int and the following columns will be ints, and this is going to stay constant, it's as simple as

```
result = [line[:1] + map(int, line[1:]) for line in lines]
```

Assuming this structure, this is the simplest way I can think of to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want "all columns but the first", it's hard to beat [John Kiparsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812847/908494). And if you want "all columns that can be converted should be", [m.wasowski's `try_int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812723/908494) is clean and simple.

But if you want something more general, that can be later expanded to, say, columns 1, 2, 3, and 7:

```
int_columns = {1, 2, 3, 7}
test = [[int(x) if i in int_columns else x for i, x in enumerate(row)]
        for row in raw_csv]
```

But I'd probably refactor it into a reusable function:

```
def map_some(func, iterable, columns):
    return [func(x) if i in columns else x for i, x in enumerate(iterable)]
test = [map_some(int, row, int_columns) for row in raw_csv]
```

Answer (score -1):

a simple approach:

```
l = [['airport', '2007', '175702', '32788'], ['airport', '2008', '173294', '31271'], ['request', '2005', '646179', '81592'], ['request', '2006', '677820', '86967'], ['request', '2007', '697645', '92342'], ['request', '2008', '795265', '125775'], ['wandered', '2005', '83769', '32682'], ['wandered', '2006', '87688', '34647'], ['wandered', '2007', '108634', '40101'], ['wandered', '2008', '171015', '64395']]
[ [x[0]]+map(int,x[1:]) for x in l ]
```

output:

```
[['airport', 2007, 175702, 32788], ['airport', 2008, 173294, 31271], ['request', 2005, 646179, 81592], ['request', 2006, 677820, 86967], ['request', 2007, 697645, 92342], ['request', 2008, 795265, 125775], ['wandered', 2005, 83769, 32682], ['wandered', 2006, 87688, 34647], ['wandered', 2007, 108634, 40101], ['wandered', 2008, 171015, 64395]]
```

Comment: give the explanation too , where i am wrong or correct me

Comment: I'm not sure about the split() - what's going on there? I suspect that that's going to give a wrong answer for something like ['gas station', '2007', '4532', '123454'], no?

Comment: yea but in input its only one word so ,i did it

Comment: That's probably why the downvote - if the split ever happens, then it's a mistake, and if it doesn't happen then it's a needless operation. I assume it's there to force a list out of the first element - but that's not the way to do that. `[x[0]]` or `list(x[0])` would be better. (I didn't downvote the post, though, so I'm just guessing)

Comment: Right, I always forget about that. Idiotic behavior, if you ask me. Fixed the reference.

Comment: same as me, i also forget about it sometime and wonder, why my output is piss me off

Comment: Now that you've edited it, this is exactly the same as the answer by @JonKiparsky, so it doesn't really add anything. So why not just delete it and get the downvote rep back?